# Have there been any non-Vedantic commentaries on the Bhagavad Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, vedanta, yoga, purva-mimamsa, abhinavagupta

The Bhagavad Gita is considered one of the key principal text in the Vedanta school along with the Mukhya Upanishads and the Brahma Sutras. There have been many commentators on the text by members of the Vedanta school such as Ramanujacharya and Adi-Shankaracharya.

But what I'm interested to know is whether any members of other philosophical schools i.e. schools other than the Vedanta school, such as the Yoga school, have written any commentary on the text? One non-Vedantic commentator I know of is the Acharya Abhinavagupta, belonging to the Trika sect. Are there any other non-Vedantic commentaries other than Acharya Abhinavagupta's?

Comment: Yes there's Bhagavad Gita written from a Yogic point of view.

Comment: Sanatana Dharma is such that there are various ways to look at and unite with God. From Dvaita to Advaita to Yogic to Siddha to vedas everything is right. None are wrong nor none spoke about their beliefs. Belief is wrong word for knowing God. It's that they wrote about their own path way of reaching God out of infinite paths available to get back to our home, from where we came.

Comment: There have been commentaries by scholars, both Western and Eastern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes as far as I know Rishi Aurobindo has authored a commentary on the Gita from a different angle. That doesn't discard his knowledge of Vedanta, but his main area was Yoga. Hence he expounded his idea from the Yoga Darshana viewpoint.

You can read the translation [here](http://intyoga.online.fr/bg_idx.htm).

However this translation is not a commentary. This itself has been taken from his book Essays On The Gita, which is the bridge between his translations and commentary. You can read "Essays" [here](http://intyoga.online.fr/arya-lit.htm#eog).