# How many prominent and most accepted commentaries are there on the Bhagavad-Gita?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

How many prominent and most accepted commentaries on the Srimad Bhagavad-Gita are there? Which sects or schools of thought are those? 
Please mention the Vedantic and non-Vedantic schools of thought as well.

Comment: Related [Have there been any non-Vedantic commentaries on the Bhagavad Gita?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/28832/3500)

Comment: Thanks @TheDestroyer. But the first thing I need to understand is that what do you mean by Vedantic or non-Vedantic commentary? And can I post this as a separate question?

Comment: Vedantic commentaries refer to commentaries expounded by the Vedanta school. There are six main Astika schools of thought in Hinduism: Vedanta, Yoga, Nyaya, Vaisheshika, Samkhya, Mimamsa. Of these, Vedanta school is the most popular.

Comment: You can get answer to your question here - https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita

Comment: @D.Chatterjee pl visit the Gita site maintained by the Kanpur IIT.You get all the most accepted commentaries there.

Comment: @D.Chatterjee BTW what do you mean by 'most accepted'? Most accepted by saints, scholars or the masses? I am asking this because circulation does not indicate acceptence as price, selling strategy, production--many such things are involved.

Comment: @Partha Thank you. I have been to the IIT Kanpur site. It has translation/commentary by monks of RK MIssion and some other saints. My question is pertaining to the most accepted or schools of thought or sects and not just by individuals. Also there's a part on vedantic and non-vedantic categories.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I'm aware of thirty-three commentaries on the Bhagavad-Gita:

---

### Achintya-Bheda-Abheda Vedanta

• Sarartha Varsini Tika, Vishvanatha Chakrabarti Thakura's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://archive.org/download/BhagavadGitaSararthaVarsiniTikaByVishvanathaCakravartiThakura/Bhagavad-Gita%20Sarartha-Varsini-Tika%20by%20Vishvanatha%20Cakravarti%20Thakura.pdf).

• Gita Bhusana, Baladeva Vidyabhusana's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://archive.org/download/BhagavadGitaGitaBhushanaByBaladevaVidyabhushana/Bhagavad-Gita%20Gita-Bhushana%20by%20Baladeva%20Vidyabhushana.pdf).

• Satyanarayan Das Babaji's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can buy it in English [**here**](https://www.jiva.org/store/Bhagavad-Gita-p76426641).

• Bhagavad-Gita As It Is, A.C. Bhaktivedanta Swami Prabhupada's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.bhagavatgita.ru/files/Bhagavad-gita_As_It_Is.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwik3YH_rPTgAhUFpI8KHYvEC18QFjAAegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw0H4mVDY6VpnlWL-55SKRdq).

• B.R. Sridhara Maharaj's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](http://www.bvml.org/SBRSM/books/GITA.PDF).

• Bhaktivinoda Thakura's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://kupdf.net/download/bhaktivinoda-thakura-rasika-ranjana-bhagavad-gita-commentary_5903541ddc0d60561e959ed9_pdf).

---

### Advaita Vedanta

• Adi-Shankaracharya's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://michaelsudduth.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Srimad-Bhagavad-Gita-Shankara-Bhashya-English.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjc3oThp_TgAhUIM48KHX3QAdQQFjAEegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw29rc4dkB7ciBd0f5XA0Rk_).

• Bhavartha Dipika, Dhyaneshwar's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://estudantedavedanta.net/Sri-Jnandevas-Bhvartha-Dipika-Jnaneswari_smaller.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjty-62qfTgAhWKuo8KHQpsBYMQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw0G-2ioNbJUAP_OBuYVKEcz).

• Gutharta Dipika, Madhusudana Saraswati's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can buy it in English [**here**](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/m/book/details/bhagavad-gita-with-commentary-of-madhusudan-saraswati-2-volumes-set-HAA761/).

• The Holy Geeta, Swami Chinmayananda's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://factmuseum.com/pdf/upaveda/Holy-Geeta-by-Swami-Chinmayananda.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjR0MakqvTgAhUfTo8KHaz-A2EQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw2EB3qGMuf-ws_OyXn1m0WJ).

• Geeta Rahashya, Bal Gangadhara Tilak's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://archive.org/compress/SrimadBhagavadGitaRahasya-BgTilak-Volumes1And2/formats=IMAGE%20CONTAINER%20PDF&file=/SrimadBhagavadGitaRahasya-BgTilak-Volumes1And2.zip).

• Swami Sivananda's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.dlshq.org/download/bgita.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwic1f_Kr_TgAhVKo48KHa88Cw4QFjABegQIAhAB&usg=AOvVaw1hSapYkkhhiX1phf9atlLM&cshid=1552110938347).

• Swami Chidbhavananda's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.amazon.in/Bhagavad-Gita-Swami-Chidbhavananda-ebook/dp/B078R61SD9).

• Sarvepalli Radhakrishnan's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.amazon.in/Bhagavad-Gita-Swami-Chidbhavananda-ebook/dp/B078R61SD9).

• Discourses on the Gita, Mohandas Gandhi's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.gandhiashramsevagram.org/pdf-books/discourses-on-gita.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiF0MejzvTgAhUIqY8KHSWtCCAQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1yyehu4Bo3Pg6gJP1NZHby).

• Talks on the Bhagavad-Gita, Vinod Bhave's can on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.mkgandhi.org/vinoba/gita.htm).

---

### Shuddhadvaita Vedanta

• Sridhara Swami's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can buy it in English [**here**](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/m/book/details/srimad-bhagavad-gita-with-commentary-by-sridhara-swami-IDK748/).

---

### Dvaita Vedanta

• Madhvacharya's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://nageshsonde.com/bhagavad_gita.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwj2oJSeqPTgAhWbknAKHXdYAYAQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw05yOukq67ZCmVuHSeyXqQ1).

• Jayatirtha's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can buy it in Sanskrit [**here**](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/m/book/details/gita-bhashyam-with-commentary-of-sri-jayatirtha-and-sri-raghavendratirtha-NZG165/).

• Raghavendratirtha's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can buy it in Sanskrit [**here**](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/m/book/details/gita-bhashyam-with-commentary-of-sri-jayatirtha-and-sri-raghavendratirtha-NZG165/).

---

### Integral Yoga

• Essays on the Gita, Sri Aurobindo's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.holybooks.com/wp-content/uploads/Sri-Aurobindo-VOL-19-Essays-On-The-Gita.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjEu__PzfTgAhVck3AKHbLQCC8QFjABegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw3yicGzaFwEQ2xDkic0pwzJ).

---

### Kashmiri Shaivism

• Gitartha Sangraha, Acharya Abhinavagupta's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://ayco.it/files/963/Yoga/0BwEwR7MZZMxITjhvU2JoS1hNeVk/ABHINAVAGUPTA%2520-Bhagavad-Gita-Commentary-by-AbhinavaGupta.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwju7NG1yPTgAhUZbysKHWukBPAQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw280KhI_9OYg23HSuVrYVpC).

---

### Kriya Yoga

• God Talks with Arjuna: The Bhagavad-Gita, Paramahamsa Yogananda's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can buy it in English [**here**](https://www.amazon.in/God-Talks-Arjuna-Bhagavad-Gita/dp/0876120311).

---

### Shivadvaita Vedanta

• Srikantha Sivacharya's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita.

---

### Svabhavika-Bheda-Abheda Vedanta

• Yadava Prakasha's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita.

---

### Vishishtadvaita Vedanta

• Swami Ramabhadracharya's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it both in Sanskrit and Hindi in a set of two volumes [**here**](https://archive.org/download/JR1998GitabhasyamI/JR1998GitabhasyamI.pdf) and [**here**](https://archive.org/details/JR1998GitabhasyamII).

• Ramanujacharya's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.srimatham.com/uploads/5/5/4/9/5549439/ramanuja_gita_bhashya.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi5ubbLp_TgAhXLv48KHeiTB5YQFjAAegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw25ubVyL86q5XOMSj7lwp75&cshid=1552108745776).

• Muktananda Swami's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita.

• Gopalananda Swami's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can read it in English [**here**](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3ykXFHcsqiObHRhb3pZVDNzVlk).

---

**Miscellaneous:**

• My Gita, Devdutt Pattnaik's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can buy it in English [**here**](https://www.amazon.in/My-Gita-Devdutt-Pattanaik/dp/8129137704).

• Bhagavad-Gita: A Text & Commentary for Students, Jeanne Fowler's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can buy it in English [**here**](https://www.amazon.in/Bhagavad-Gita-Commentary-Religious-Practices/dp/1845193466).

• Exploring the Bhagavad-Gita: Philosophy, Structure and Meaning, Ithamar Theodore's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can buy it in English [**here**](https://www.amazon.in/Exploring-Bhagavad-Gita-Philosophy-Structure-ebook/dp/B00D3JBI88).

• F. Edgerton's commentary on the Bhagavad-Gita. You can buy it in English [**here**](https://www.amazon.in/Bhagavad-Gita-Vols-Harvard-Oriental/dp/8120811496/ref=mp_s_a_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1552137904&sr=1-2&refinements=p_27%3AF.%20Edgerton&pi=AC_SX118_SY170_FMwebp_QL65).

---

Comment: Nice compilation - but note that only some of those are bhashyas written for the original work that existed at that time. Examples of these are Sri Sankara Bhashya, Sri Ramanuja Bhashya etc. The others like Sri Radakrishnan's, and works by other modern authors are explanation on the original bhashyams. They are more like further comment or elaboration of the bhashyas.

Answer (score 2):

Wonder no one included Gita Vahini..

It's good that no one included it and it deserves a separate place.

This is written by Bhagavan Satya Sai Baba, named Gita Vahini, a beautiful explanation of Bhagavad gita which you can relish for free from [here](http://www.sathyasai.org/teachings/vahini/gita-vahini).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gita Vahini already mentioned by user Prem,

There is one more beautiful explnations verse by verse by Satya Sai Baba.

You can read it from http://bababooks.org/SathyaSaiGita/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the "most accepted" part, as there doesn't seem to be a consensus among the scholars. But here is a site that enumerates many available commentaries if not all.

https://www.speakingtree.in/blog/45-commentaries-on-bhagavad-gita-195895

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Surya's very exhaustive answer, I want to added a few:

▪ Commentary by Yogiraj Shyamacharan Lahiri based on the Yoga Philosophy

▪ Commentary by Ballavacharya based on the Suddha-Avaita Marga of the Vedanta Philosophy

▪ Keshava Kashmiri Bhatta's commentary (Gita-Tattva-Prakashika) of the Dvaitaaadvaita Marga of the Vedanta Philosophy

▪ Rajanaka and Ramabhatta's commentary (Sarvato-Bhadra) based on the Shaiva Philosophy

**One thing we have to remember: Tika and Bhashya are not the same, even though many of us use 'Commentary' as translations of both. For example,**

(a) Sri Adi Sankaracharya wrote bhashya of Gita following the Advaita Philosophy. Sri Ananda Giri and Sri Ramananda wrotes Tikas named 'Vivarana' and 'Vyakhyaa' of that bhashya respectively.

(b) Sri Ramanujachaya wrote bhashya of Gita following the Vishistadvaita philosophy of Vedanta. Sri Venkatanatha or Vedantaacharya wrote the Tika named 'Tatparya-chandrika' of that bhashya.

(c) Sri Yamunacharya, the Guru of Sri Ramanujacharya wrote 'Gitaartha-Sangraha' on which Sri Nigamanta Madesika wrote Gitartha-Sangraha-Rakshana' Tika and Sri Varavara Muni wrote the Gitartha-Sangraha-Dipika' tika.

Note that the bhashyas has been written in sanskrit and explain meaning of each word in sanskrit in detail unlike ISKCON's 'Gita as it is' or Devdutt Pattnaik's 'My Gita' .The last two are originally in English.

Comment: "I would never suggest any serious reader of the Gita to read especially the last two." This is not expected, the question is not asking personal views.

Comment: @Pandya yes, 'prominent' and 'most accepred' are subjective evaluations