# what is the meaning of Knowledge and wisdom in Gita chapter 6 verse 8?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita

[Source](https://shlokam.org/bhagavad-gita/6-8/)

Gita  chapter 6 verse 8

> jñānavijñānatṛptātmā kūṭastho vijitendriyaḥ
> yukta ityucyate yogī samaloṣṭāśmakāñcanaḥ

**Meaning** :The YOGI who is satisfied with knowledge and wisdom, who remains unshaken, who has conquered the senses, to whom a lump of earth, a stone and gold are the same, is said to be harmonised (i. e. , is said to have attained NIRVIKALPA SAMADHI) .

**My confusion**  : what  is the  meaning of  Knowledge and wisdom in this verse?

In what sense is knowledge and wisdom used in this verse?

Specifically, I want to know what type of knowledge and wisdom

**Oxford Dictionary** : knowledge mean information and  Wisdom mean  intelligence

Comment: Oxford dictionary, is insufficient to convey the import of what knowledge/ignorance could mean in this context..It is usual to attribute knowledge/ignorance to intellect, in common...Here, in the scope of Gita it is narrowness of understanding if it is assumed , this way., Whatever action (by thoughts , speech, body) done, is rooted on desire or attachment which again is grounded on spiritual ignorance or avidya(here it is not about intellectually not knowing etc).

Comment: Spiritual wisdom, is a direct experience (aparoksha anubhuti) that occurs only when mind is calm (when thoughts doesn't rattle)..All scientific claims are valid until another evidence sets a timeline for its validity. However, spiritual wisdom is eternally valid (Nithya).It is the Parama purushartha(highest possible attaintment of human life)Here, attitude is of value . It is not about intellectual acquisition of facts

Comment: You can try reading commentaries on BG written by our legendary Acharyas like Shripad Adi Shankaracharya, Ramanujacharya, Madhvacharya and many more from [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/33621/how-many-prominent-and-most-accepted-commentaries-are-there-on-the-bhagavad-gita)(PS. refer to the first answer and stick to the commentaries linked to acharyas of a bonafide sampradaya and not that of ppl like Devdutt Pattanaik which are also mentioned in the ans)....Hope this helps

Comment: Please reply to this comment if you feel that question is not duplicate.

Comment: @Pandya I agree, my question is  duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two key words are jnana and vijnana (jñānavijñāna). The word Jnana means scriptural knowledge while Vijnana translated as wisdom means direct experience of the truth according to some commentators.

> The clarity of understanding obtained through the intellectual pursuit
> and pious study of the scripture goes by the nomenclature, jnana or
> knowledge; but that is not sufficient by itself. It has to culminate
> in vijnana - intuition which is mentioned here as wisdom. The Truth
> cogitated upon becomes cognized and the yogi delights both in the
> process and attainment.

**Commentary on Gita 6.8 by Swami Chidbhavananda**